# Need clarification between URLError. dataNotAllowed and URLError.notConnectedToInternet

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nserror, nsurlsessiondatatask

I tried to handle URLSession dataTask error. When dataTask is started without internet connection , i'm getting URLError.dataNotAllowed error. When will I get URLError.notConnectedToInternet ?

Comment: `URLError` doesn't seem to have a `noInternetConnection` property. Are you referring to [.notConnectedToInternet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlerror/2293104-notconnectedtointernet)?

Comment: Sorry ,my bad. Actually it's URLError.notConnectedToInternet